# Connect to another ftp server .db

Tags: php, sqlite, ftp

I was wondering if it's possible to connect to another ftp server and edit files in there. To be more specific I want to connect to ftp server, locate .db file sqlite version 3, edit and save it with php. How do I do it? Thanks !

Comment: Certainly that is possible. I suggest you simply start by reading the documentation of the `ftp` extension php has: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: huh alright. Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. The FTP protocol has no real capability to read and write only parts of a file or to lock a file. This means essentially that you need to transfer the file to your local machine, edit it there and then transfer it back.

Comment: @MartynasJakas Whilst this is technically true it might be worth taking a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php